# Switching on keyboard backlight on a ASUS vivobook 15 (X512DA)

Tags: asus

I bought this ASUS vivobook on amazon and in the specifics there was the keyboard backlight, switchable with a function key (f7 in this case). The main problem is that my laptop doesn't have the icon showed in the guide [User manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/E402YA/0409_E14573_X412_X512_A.pdf) but the keys are transparent, making them difficult to see in some situations.

I still haven't tried a key mapping but the settings doesn't seems to exits in the computer.

p.s. I searched on google the X512DA and the same product that sells amazon now have the icon, basically my problem is not having the icon at all.

I just need a feedback from other people that have the same product or problem. (or if you have a method to resolve this it's well accepted)

Comment: Have you already seen the relevant [support page on Asus's website](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1014790)? That claims that models that do not have the symbol do not have a backlit keyboard.

Comment: Yes, I had, and at this point I have lost hope for this function. It remains only the strange fact that my keys are transparent. (I saw the red line written on the guide that you sent but the keys for now are the only evidence). Also thank you.